# Get [x,z] contained in frustum

Tags: 3d, xna

Using the 8 corners that can be returned from a frustum, how would I go about getting an array of all the points that are contained in this frustum?

For my specific case I dont need the y coordinate just the x,z coordinates.

Ive actually given this quite a bit of thought and havnt come to any solution, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using XNA you can run a bunch of coordinates through a BoundingFrustrum's Contains method.

```
var frustum = new BoundingFrustum(ViewMatrix);
if(frustum.Contains(new Vector3(0,0,0))) {
    // This point is in the frustum, add it to a list of points
}
```